# log4j2 not writing to the log file with rollingFile appenders

Tags: xml, log4j2

I am new using log4j2

I am trying to configure the xml to send the logs into the log file using the  and  appenders. Well, the  appender works fine. I want to use  appender so that it will clear the log file daily, but when it first created the log file, it doesn't write any log message into the file created by , so I came here to get some advise

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="FATAL" >

<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern}" />
    </Console>
    
    <RollingFile name="rollingfile" fileName="rolling.log"
    filePattern="rolling-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern}" />
        <Policies>
              <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
              <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB" />
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
    
    <File name="file" fileName="test2.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern}" />
    </File>     
    
</Appenders>


<Loggers>   
    <Root level="trace" >
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        <AppenderRef ref="rollingfile" />
        <AppenderRef ref="file" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: <AppenderRef ref="rollingfile" />

Comment: Oh yeah i just figured it out with double check :/
Sorry about that
but yet after i correct it with the same name as "rollingfile" the log file still empty how many times i reflash my page try to generate the log record, fine to the "file" appender but the "rollingfile" still empty :/ 
i cannot figure out why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `AppenderRef="rolling"`, but your Appender is named "rollingfile". These need to match.

Also, log4j probably issues a warning that there is a problem with the configuration. I recommend you specify `<Configuration status="WARN" >` at the start of your config instead of FATAL so that you can see these warnings.

It may be that you need to specify `${sys:pattern}` to read the system property. Instead of the `${pattern}` variable, first try an explicit pattern like `%d %p [%t] %m%n`.

Comment: Oh yeah i just figured it out with double check :/
Sorry about that
but yet after i correct it with the same name as "rollingfile" the log file still empty how many times i reflash my page try to generate the log record, fine to the "file" appender but the "rollingfile" still empty :/ 
i cannot figure out why

Comment: Updated: use `sys:` prefix for system property lookup.