# log4j2 RollingFIle not writing logs to file in weblogic

Tags: xml, log4j2, weblogic12c, rollingfileappender

I have configured ther log4j2 in weblogic 12c.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="info">

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d [%t] %-5p - %m\n" />
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="RollingFile">
            <FileName>app.log</FileName>
            <FilePattern>app-%d.log</FilePattern>
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>    
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>   
        <Root level="all">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

My file is generated but logs are not written in file. I found same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36996935/log4j2-not-writing-to-the-log-file-with-rollingfile-appenders), but my appenders names are same. What wrong I'm doing?

Any one who facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem for logging in file. It worked by moving the `AppenderRef` to `Logger`.

```
<Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.yourloggername" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Logger>
</Loggers>
```